# How to copy calculated fields from shared datset to embeded dataset

Tags: reporting-services

How to copy calculated fields from shared dataset to embeded dataset?

previously i used shared dataset, and now need to change to embedded dataset
i have added calculated fields in my previous dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either...

Open the shared dataset (`.rsd`) file in a text editor either from your solution  (or download it from the web portal). Then you can copy/paste the expression into your embedded dataset. You could just paste them directly into the report's `.rdl` file at the end of the dataset block.

Or, if your existing report uses the old shared dataset, open the `rdl` in a text editor, look for the shared dataset reference, it will look something like this..

```
 <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <SharedDataSet>
        <SharedDataSetReference>mySharedDataset</SharedDataSetReference>
      </SharedDataSet>
      <Fields>
...
...
...
```

Then replace it with the query from the shared dataset, something like this.

```
<DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT * FROM myTable</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
...
...
...
```

You will need to add the datasource reference first though

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left above the vote up/down buttons) . This helps other SO users find answers to similar questions in the future.